# How to subtract values from one row from values of another row using Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am fairly new to fortran and am using it for some molecular dynamics work
I have a text file that contains xyz coordinates of multiple atoms. Edit: The data is repetitive

```
12
xyz
OH2        2.056771        0.152501       -3.407425
H1         2.086389       -0.658114       -2.899234
H2         1.325328        0.643692       -3.033321
OH2       -1.620865        1.026821       -4.353753
H1        -1.045534        1.344086       -5.049863
H2        -1.107708        1.130454       -3.552402
OH2       -2.064113        1.377066       -1.093998
H1        -1.228430        1.344786       -1.559641
H2        -2.692285        1.681116       -1.749120
OH2        1.451636        1.645941       -0.456822
H1         0.841741        1.630468       -1.194400
H2         1.251076        0.850951        0.037141
```

Where OH2 and H1/H2 are atoms.
I would like to be able subtract the xyz coor of the H2(hydrogen) following the preceding OH2(oxygen) for every OH2 that is recognized.
So far my code looks as follows:

```
  program placepoint
  implicit none
  real(kind(0.0d0)) :: xCoor(1:12), yCoor(1:12), zCoor(1:12)
  real(kind(0.0d0)) :: v1_x, v1_y, v1_z, dOH, nx, ny, nz
  real(kind(0.0d0)) :: ip_x, ip_y, ip_z, norm
  integer :: j, n
  character*20 :: dumch(1:12)

  open(unit = 10, file = 'hoh.xyz')
  open(unit = 13, file = 'ipcoor.txt')
  do j= 1, 12
  read(10,*) dumch(j) , xCoor(j), yCoor(j), zCoor(j)

  !Calculate vector 1 along OXR-HX bond that can be used to place a point ip (R1)
  if (dumch(j) .eq. "OH2") then
  v1_x = xCoor(j+2) - xCoor(j) 
  v1_y = yCoor(j+2) - yCoor(j)
  v1_z = zCoor(j+2) - zCoor(j)
  dOH = sqrt((v1_x)**2 + (v1_y)**2 + (v1_z)**2)

 ! Normalize vector 
  nx = v1_x/dOH
  ny = v1_y/dOH
  nz = v1_z/dOH

 !Place ip at 0.7Å along the OH bond (this is not exactly at the correct HX-OXR-OR angle but these are for dummy atoms and shake should take care of this during dyn runs) 
  ip_x = xCoor(1) + 0.7*nx
  ip_y = yCoor(1) + 0.7*ny
  ip_z = zCoor(1) + 0.7*nz
  
  end if
  end do
  write(13,*) 'ip' , ip_x, ip_y, ip_z, dOH

  end program place point
```

I realize I am being to naive using the j+2 as a identifier to find the value of H2 immediately following the OH2, but unfortunately I have not found any other better way. I also get the fortran error "End of file" after proper compilation. So I am expecting that I am perhaps making multiple mistakes here. Any help with this will be so appreciated!

Comment: The essence of the answer is to break it into two steps - first read in the data, and once you have read it all in and so know all the positions calculate the distances of interest. But before I think about writing answer you talk about j+1 in the text of you question, but the code has j+2. Which is it?

Comment: And BTW it is impossible to answer the part about "end of file" with what you have shown here. It is much, *much* better to show an example input file and the full code you are actually using rather than some sort of skeleton - if you do the former we can compile and  test exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you @IanBush for your comments. I have edited the post accordingly. I am only interested in the distance between atoms at j and j+2 positions, hope this clears up any confusion!